# modalpopupextender not working in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using modalpopupextender in usercontrol and show in a page.
 Even set modalpopupextender's Enabled = true
 It will not the popup pls see the image
Please  help to resolve this issue[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following once you enables the Modal Popup Extender:

MPPE1.show()